# Proper way to import modules and run flask app

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, python-import

I have a flask application that I am running. I am currently running the app as a python script using flasks command app.run()

The script currently looks like

```py
from src.pkg1 import func1
from src.pkg2 import func2

app = flask.Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    return('Hello world')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

This works great when running this app.py file as a python script.

the file structure is the root repository directory contains a src folder with all the code that needs to be run. However the problem is that when I try to run the app using `flask run` I get an error.

if i `cd` into the src folder and run `flask run` the output i get is

```
Error: While importing "repo.src.app", an ImportError was raised:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\folder\repo\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 240, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "D:\folder\repo\src\app.py", line 3, in <module>
    from src.pkg1 import func1
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
```

I can solve this problem by changin the imports to relative like so

```py
from .pkg1 import func1
from .pkg2 import func2

app = flask.Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    return('Hello world')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

But then running the app as a python script wont work and the output is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/folder/repo/src/app.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .pkg1 import func1
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.pkg1'; '__main__' is not a package
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix this? Why does running `flask run` treat the app differently. What is the expected use for relative and absolute imports?

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an `__init__.py` file in your `src` directory. In the `__init__.py` file import `pkg1` and `pkg2` so if should be like:

```py
# __init__.py

import pkg1
import pkg2
```

Or you can change the structure of you directory:

Before:

```
scr
 |
 - pkg1.py
 |
 - pkg2.py
 |
 - app.py
```

After:

```
scr
 |
 - app.py
 |
 - pkgs
    |
    - pkg1.py
    |
    - pkg2.py
```

Comment: I have an `__init__.py` file in the src directory. Is there anything else that should be done?

Comment: @JoshZwiebel Please in the `__init__.py` import pkg1 and pkg2

Comment: import src.pkg1?

Comment: @JoshZwiebel No. `import pkg1` (check to updated answer)

Comment: I'm getting an error that says no module named pkg1 even though they are in the same directory

Comment: @JoshZwiebel Please move all your `pkg`'s into a different directory and import from that folder/

Comment: Shouldn't all the code the app.py needs be in the same folder?

Comment: @JoshZwiebel Please check the answer.

Comment: What does this change about the way python handles imports?

Comment: and what is the difference between the flask run command and running it as a script. This does not seem to have fixed the issue

Comment: @JoshZwiebel Do you import `app.py` in your `pkgs`? (for me seems like no difference between `flask run` and running the normal script)

Comment: Doesn't this still require `app = Flask(__name__)` to be in the module being imported? Throws an error otherwise but wondering if by including it it's spinning up a separate flask instance